# Contar todos los caracteres excepto unos cuantos

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estoy intentando contar todos los caracteres de un string que no sean cuatro que tengo reservados.

por ejemplo:

s.count(quiero todos los caracteres de un string(s) excepto 4: a, c t y g)
como podría contar todos ellos exceptuando los cuatro mencionados?

En un ejemplo practico seria el siguiente caso:

```
 s = 'acaaaaattgggaaacccccbvbm2xyyuuooopp5585'
s.count('a')
s.count('t')
s.count('g')
s.count('c')
s.count(all except 'a','t','c','g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas más simples es usando comprensión de listas de la siguiente forma:

```
s = 'acaaaaattgggaaacccccbvbm2xyyuuooopp5585'
excepto = ['a','t','c','g']

print("Cantidad: {0}".format(len([l for l in s if l not in excepto])))
```

Esto: `[l for l in s if l not in excepto]` convierte la cadena `s` en una lista de letras que no estuvieran presentes en la lista `excepto`, lo que resta es simplemente obtener la longitud con `len` para saber la cantidad de letras.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la misma idea que la expuesta por Patricio en su respuesta, una forma algo mas eficiente aunque realmente no se va a notar en cadenas pequeñas como la tuya es usar `string.translate` para eliminar los caracteres excluidos de la cadena:

```
print(len(s.translate({ord(c): None for c in 'atgc'})))
```

No obstante, si como das a entender requieres del número de veces que aparecen tambien 'a', 'g', 't' y 'c' lo mas eficiente con diferencia es usar [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) en vez de aplicar `str.count` cuatro veces sobre la cadena. Más aún si lo que estas tratando de contar son bases de una cadena  genética donde se espera que la mayor parte de los caracteres sean A,T, G y C:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'acaaaaattgggaaacccccbvbm2xyyuuooopp5585'
c = Counter(s)
print("'a' aparece {} veces.".format(c["a"]))
print("'t' aparece {} veces.".format(c["t"]))
print("'g' aparece {} veces.".format(c["g"]))
print("'c' aparece {} veces.".format(c["c"]))
print("Caracteres diferentes a 'a', 'g', 't' y 'c' aparecen {} veces.".format(len(s) - c["a"] - c["g"] -c["t"] -c["c"]))
```

**Salida:**

> 'a' aparece 9 veces.
>   't' aparece 2 veces.
>   'g' aparece 3 veces.
>   'c' aparece 6 veces.
>   Caracteres diferentes a 'a', 't', 'g' y 'c' aparecen 19 veces.